# World of Warcraft Cataclysm MMO Gaming Mouse (SteelSeries) not functioning, any way to sort this?

Tags: mouse, input-devices

Pretty new to Ubuntu and Linux for home use as a whole, anything I've done in the past has been simple server work so I've never had to deal with troubleshooting my own hardware before, anyway.

I currently have a SteelSeries "World of Warcraft Cataclysm MMO Gaming Mouse", which I bought several years ago. When using this with Windows and the SteelSeries downloaded mouse package I was able to use the mouse with no problems whatsoever, however on booting into ubuntu for the first time today, I am completely unable to use the mouse for anything, the courser does not respond to any interaction whatsoever.

I've seen posts on the ubuntu forums about the same mouse, but these people appear to be struggling to use the additional buttons on the mouse rather than use the mouse for typical activity. I'm not too bothered about using the additional buttons having given up MMO gaming years ago, but these people seem to be able to use the mouse for normal mouse-y things like pointing and clicking whilst I'm struggling to get that far. That's all I want to achieve.

I had no issues with using the mouse when trying out a debian live CD earlier today, though I subsequently switched straight to a fresh install of ubuntu on booting for the first time into my debian install and finding the mouse wasn't working, thinking that this was probably a nonfree drivers issue that ubuntu would be far more able to cope with.

Is there anything I can do or anywhere I can look to perhaps figure out what I need to do to get this thing working? Thanks.

Using xinput I get:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SteelSeries World of Warcraft: Cataclysm MMO Gaming Mouse id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SteelSeries World of Warcraft: Cataclysm MMO Gaming Mouse id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ SteelSeries World of Warcraft: Cataclysm MMO Gaming Mouse id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CHESEN USB Keyboard                       id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CHESEN USB Keyboard                       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Are any events generated by the input subsystem?

Comment: Hey Ignacio, thanks for replying so soon. I'd love to be able to answer you but I have no idea where to look to find that, as I said, completely new to this environment :( sorry.

Comment: Have you had any success with this problem ? I've the same one.

Comment: can you add the output of `uname -a` , then `dmesg | tail -n 20` right after plugged mouse in and of `lsusb -v` when mouse is plugged?

Answer (score 0):

Your mouse is emulating a keyboard and four mice.

I would stipulate that it's emulating the keyboard so it can do macros on the buttons.

I would also stipulate that it's emulating four mice so it can increase the perceived DPI by reading all four mouse pointers and using position triangulation.

To get the pointer working you have to figure out which pointer is the actual mouse and configure the window manager to use that pointer.

I don't know how to reconfigure that in Ubuntu's current window manager, but there you have it.